# Finding the magnetic flux density using Lorentz force

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I am having troubles solving a question

The question is: A particle moves so that its position vector is given by:

**r**(t) = $Rcos(\omega t)$ ***i*** +$Rsin(\omega t)$ ***j***, where R and $\omega$ are positive contants and ***i*** and ***j*** are unit vectors in the x and y directions.

Assume that the particle is a charge q with mass m subject to a magnetic force $q\dot{r}$ $\times$ **B**. Determine **B** assuming it is parallel to the unit vector **k** = ***i*** $\times$ ***j***

I know the magnetic force is found from the Lorentz force **F** = q(**E** + ***v*** $\times$ **B**). In this case there is no Electric field. So **F** = q ***v*** $\times$ **B**,  where ***v*** = **$\dot{r}$**. I'm not sure how I would find **B**. Do I just find a vector that is parallel to **k** = ***i*** $\times$ ***j*** ?
Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: I guess you need to compute $\ddot r$ and $\dot r$ and substitute into Lorentz formula?

Comment: @mathshungry I calculated ${r}''$ and $\dot{r}$ and substituted into the formula by setting **F** = m${r}''$ = q$\dot{r}$ $\times$ **B**. Not sure what I would do from there. (sorry, don't know how to format r double dot)

Comment: Is there a problem in ${\bf r}(t)$? It appears to be $R\cos(\omega t)({\bf i}+{\bf j})$.

Comment: @Jon Ah thank you for that, it's meant to be **R**sin($\omega$ t) **j**. I have edited the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be worked out in the following way. Take the first derivative of the position
$$
  \dot{\bf r}(t)=-\omega R\sin(\omega t){\bf i}+\omega R\cos(\omega t){\bf j}
$$
and the second one
$$
  \ddot{\bf r}(t)=-\omega^2 R\cos(\omega t){\bf i}-\omega^2 R\cos(\omega t){\bf j}
$$
and you realize that $\ddot{\bf r}(t)=-\omega^2{\bf r}$. Then you will use the Lorentz equation to get
$$
   m\ddot{\bf r}(t)=-m\omega^2{\bf r}(t)=q\dot{\bf r}(t)\times{\bf B}.
$$
Choose $B{\bf k}$ and do the vector product. You will get
$$
  -m\omega^2 R\cos(\omega t)=q\omega R\cos(\omega t)B
$$
$$
  -m\omega^2 R\sin(\omega t)=q\omega R\sin(\omega t)B
$$
and you see that both the equations are consistent provided
$$
   B=-\frac{m\omega}{q}
$$
and, indeed,
$$
  \omega =\frac{qB}{m}
$$
is the well-known Larmor frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but shouldn't B =$\frac{ -m \omega} {q}$ ?